# Получение списка стран через VK API

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужен список стран. Решил использовать ВК АПИ. В документации пишет, что метод можно использовать без доступа ключа. Я библиотеку подключил, но не знаю, как правильно достать данные. Кто знает, как это сделать ?

Вот скрин, как не распознает базу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Запрос:

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("database.getCountries", VKParameters.from("need_all", "1"));
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(VKRequest.VKProgressType progressType, long bytesLoaded, long bytesTotal) {
                super.onProgress(progressType, bytesLoaded, bytesTotal);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                super.onError(error);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                loginRegistr.setText(response.json.toString());
            }
        });
```

Стек:

```
08-06 11:08:23.294 21949-21949/com.project.samuliak.psychogram E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.project.samuliak.psychogram, PID: 21949
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.samuliak.psychogram/com.project.samuliak.psychogram.Activity.main.registration.RegistrationDoctorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
                                                                                     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
                                                                                     at com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.tokenFromSharedPreferences(VKAccessToken.java:236)
                                                                                     at com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.currentToken(VKAccessToken.java:275)
                                                                                     at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpClient.requestWithVkRequest(VKHttpClient.java:81)
                                                                                     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.getPreparedRequest(VKRequest.java:305)
                                                                                     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.getOperation(VKRequest.java:323)
                                                                                     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.start(VKRequest.java:392)
                                                                                     at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.executeWithListener(VKRequest.java:233)
                                                                                     at com.project.samuliak.psychogram.Activity.main.registration.RegistrationDoctorActivity.initUI(RegistrationDoctorActivity.java:209)
                                                                                     at com.project.samuliak.psychogram.Activity.main.registration.RegistrationDoctorActivity.onCreate(RegistrationDoctorActivity.java:67)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: **[До - ку - мен - та - ци - я](https://new.vk.com/dev/android_sdk)** ??

Comment: все равно не могу понять, как сделать запрос на список стран

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно почитать про методы API, и руководствуясь инструкцией SDK отправлять запрос к API VK.

Вот запрос который возвращает список всех стран:

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.database().getCountries(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.
NEED_ALL, "1"));
```

И соответственно отправка запроса, вместе со слушателем 
(который выполнит действия в зависимости от того был запрос успешным или нет):

```
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) { 
    //Do complete stuff 
    } 
    @Override 
    public void onError(VKError error) { 
    //Do error stuff 
    } 
    @Override 
    public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) { 
    //I don't really believe in progress 
    } 
    });
```

Comment: Я все так и делал, но у меня почему то database() подчеркивается красным. Оно не может узнать, что это.(

Comment: даже на "da*" ничего не находит

Comment: @Samuliak попробуйте вот так `VKRequest request = new VKRequest("database.getCountries", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.NEED_ALL, "1"));`

Comment: нет такой константы, как NEED_ALL и ею подобных (

Comment: @Samuliak очень странно, но похоже что в `vk-android-sdk` действительно нет такой константы как `NEED_ALL`, http://vkcom.github.io/vk-android-sdk/com/vk/sdk/api/VKApiConst.html

Учитывая что эта константа является простой строкой, попробуйте отправить запрос такого вида: `VKRequest request = new VKRequest("database.getCountries", VKParameters.from("need_all", "1"));`

Comment: Вылетает ошибка при execute запроса. Логи прикрепил в 1-м посте.